# Creating different environments with flavours and source sets in jetpack compose

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 build variants DEBUG and RELEASE, and two flavors in a dimension, being DEV and PROD. I understand that source sets for dev and prod environments should be created following main folder's structure.

I would like to display different texts in composables in different versions of my application.

I followed tutorials which says to copy the files over to the other source sets and change whatever that is necessary. However, this files are dependent on other files that are not present in the directory. How should i be doing this?

Please do share best practices for setting up flavors as I am new to this.